# Is this really encapsulated?

Tags: python-3.x

I wondered wheather it is actually impossible to make a protected python class, there always seems to be a way of getting around that, but i can't find one for this:
I attempted to code out this properly encapsulated class. Challenge:
Attempt setting somevalue to the value 69, without:

- changing the code from line 1 - 32
- polymorphism

```py
from sbNative.debugtools import log # module not neccessary, only for logging and debugging purposes imported
from inspect import stack
import traceback


class Protected:
    def __init__(self):
        self._somevalue = "Unset"
        log(self._somevalue)
        
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if isinstance(stack()[1][0].f_locals.get("self"), Protected) or not name.startswith("_"):
            super(Protected, self).__setattr__(name, value)
        else:
            raise AttributeError("Protected class from setting")
        
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if isinstance(stack()[1][0].f_locals.get("self"), Protected) or not name.startswith("_"):
            return super(Protected, self).__getattribute__(name)
        else:
            raise AttributeError("Protected class from getting")
        
    @property
    def somevalue(self):
        return self._somevalue
        
    @somevalue.setter
    def somevalue(self, value):
        if value == 69:
            raise ValueError(f"{value} is an illegal value.")
        self._somevalue = value


log("Instantiates without a problem:")
       
p = Protected()

print("\n")

log("Fails because it is not allowed to set to this value:")

try:
    p.somevalue = 69
except ValueError:
    traceback.print_exc()

print("\n")

log("Fails because it attemps setting and getting directly:")

try:
    p._somevalue = 69
except AttributeError:
    traceback.print_exc()

print("")

try:
    log(p._somevalue)
except AttributeError:
    traceback.print_exc()

print("\n")

log("Succeeds because it is allowed to set and get this value:")

p.somevalue = 420
log(p.somevalue)
print("ⁿᶦᶜᵉ ˡᶦⁿᵉ ⁿᵘᵐᵇᵉʳ ᵇᵗʷ")
```

Comment: `super(Protected, p).__setattr__('_somevalue', 69)` sets the attribute

Comment: Hmmmmmm, true, imma look if i can prevent that somehow

Comment: Do you have an idea on how to get around this?